# How do you convert onclick events so that they work on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios

Here's what needs to be converted:

Yes     No

```
            function calculateTotal() {
                //Here we get the total points by calling our functions
                var totPoints = 0+get_r1()+get_r2()+get_r3();

                //display the result
                var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPoints');
                divobj.style.display='block';
                divobj.innerHTML = "Total: "+totPoints;                         
            }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What framework do you use? What 'Yes No' mean?

Comment: The Yes/No was supposed to be part of the code example.  They were supposed to be radio buttons with an onClick call to the javascript function calculateTotal().

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve, btw if you are not using jQuery for the events handling, the equivalent event for 'onclick' on the iOs is 'touchend' if i'm not wrong.